# It says that it has been inserted on database, but nothing appears there

Tags: php, mysql

Eu guardo a informação dos inputs no botão "Guardar " e depois diz que a informação foi inserida, mas quando vou ver a base de dados, não está lá nada,
Algém me pode ajudar?

```
<?php 
include "Conexão.php";
if(isset($_POST['Botao']))
{
$PrimeiroNome = $_POST['PrimeiroNome'];
$UltimoNome = $_POST['UltimoNome'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Telefone = $_POST['Telefone'];
$Endereço = $_POST['Endereço'];
$Aniversario = $_POST['Aniversario'];
$insert = "INSERT INTO 'lista_contactos'('PrimeiroNome', 'UltimoNome', 'Email', 'Telefone', 'Endereço','Aniversario')
VALUES ('$PrimeiroNome','$UltimoNome','$Email','$Telefone','$Endereço','$Aniversario')";
   if(!$insert)
{
echo "Erro a inserir!";
}
else
{
echo "Inserido!";
}
}?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="PrimeiroNome" placeholder="PrimeiroNome">
<input type="text" name="UltimoNome" placeholder="UltimoNome">
<input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name="Telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
<input type="text" name="Endereço" placeholder="Endereço">
<input type="date" name="Aniversario" placeholder="Aniversário">
<input type="submit" name="Botao" placeholder="Guardar">
</form>
```

Comment: Não vão aspas simples em nomes de tabelas e campos. Também precisa chamar/usar a API do banco de dados para enviar seu SQL.

Comment: Voce só criou a query mas não colocou ela na conexão

Comment: @rray 
Como faço isso ao certo?
Sou um novato em PHP :\

Comment: @MarceloRafael Como faço isso mesmo?

Comment: Voce tem que procurar tutoriais na internet pra te ensinar a fazer isso, acho que aqui não seria muito recomendado, procure no youtube por PHP PDO

Comment: Eu gosto desse cara: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtCdk459NFg&list=PLfdtiltiRHWHkDwEoZ29Q9FKtWVjA46HC se voce escreveu sua pergunta em ingles deve entender

Comment: @MarceloRafael Muito Obrigado, vou assistir agora e tentar resolver :D